# What is the difference between an Azure Cloud Service Staging Slot and an Azure Web App Staging Slot?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-roles

This question is also to do with why one gets charged double for Cloud Service instances, and I believe that the answer in my case is due to the fact that I have a Cloud Service Staging Slot which is actually a seperate VM whereas a WebSite Staging slot is just another website instance on the same VM, so you pay the same.

So to pay for one Cloud Service instance ie around 700 hours in a month, one must only have the "Production" slot, the "Staging" slot must be deleted.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Cloud Services you're paying the resources you use, meaning that if you have a Production slot and a Staging slot, you pay for both, as you already mentioned.

In App Service (Web Apps, API Apps, Mobile Apps) we support staging slots (multiple ones, not only 1) in Standard and Premium. Each plan has some Staging slots included and you don't pay anything extra. Standard has 5 and Premium has 20. You can find more information at [App Service plans](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/)

To pay only for the hours you mentioned, you need to only have either Production or Staging running, not both at the same time. Having said that, with the per minute billing Azure has, even if you have Staging running for a small amount of time until you do a swap, the impact on your bill will be really low if it's only a couple of minutes each time.

Comment: Panagiotis, Thanks for this. I guess I fell into the trap of treating the Cloud Service Slot like the Website Staging Slot, and keeping it there as a deployment slot which is no issue with Websites. However for all the minutes the staging slot runs,. I get charged. So I guess my workflow should be 1) deploy to staging 2) test, 3) swap to production, 4) delete the staging slot. Am I correct?

Comment: Am I also correct in thinking that a Cloud Service Staging Slot is a seperate VM?

Comment: Yes, both assumptions are correct. We usually keep staging running for 1-2 hours before tearing it down, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that for App Services each slot runs on the same VM so having a bunch in use at the same time could potentially effect performance.  Unlike the Cloud Services slots since they are completely separate VMs.  This isn't usually an issue but something to be aware of.

Comment: That's not entirely true. With ASE (App Service Environment) you can have control on the worker roles (VMs) and the allocation of resources (VM hosting apps) and you can even make it 1:1.